# How to change button state in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to code a function in Javacript that updates the button colour and enables it when all fields are valid.
See picture below to understand the user interaction with the form

[image]

When the admin wants to update an user the update button needs to be green only if the following apply

1. At least one edit button is enabled. (When the edit button is enabled the respective fields is deleted and the user can write something)
2. The field must be validated in real time
3. If I uncheck the field the script has to revalidate the other open fields. For Instance if the open field is blank the button should be red but if I close the field and another field was enabled and filled with valid text (lets assume just 1 character means valid) the button from red should turn green

Could you please help me to figure this out. I think a solution is to use the JQuery keyup function but it is restricted only to one field. I need instead something more global.

Is there a way in javascript to create a global button listener than be useful for this scenario

In addition when I turn on the password checkbox two fields are enabled and the button should be valid only if password is valid and it matches with confirmed password

Please see below a brief summary of the jsp page

I have omitted the small icons of the password fields and the bootstrap part of the code

```
<sf:form class="form-horizontal" 
         role="form" 
         id="formsubmit" 
         method="POST" 
         action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/updateprofile"
         commandName="user">
          <sf:input type="text" class="form-control" value="${user.username}" path="username" readonly="true"></sf:input>

         <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="email-checkbox" checked />
         <sf:input id="emailInput" type="text" class="form-control" path="email" placeholder="Type Email" name="email" disabled="true" />

        <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="first-name-checkbox" checked />
        <sf:input id="nameInput" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type First Name" path="firstName" name="firstName" disabled="true" />

        <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="last-name-checkbox" checked />
        <sf:input id="surnameInput" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type Last Name" path="lastName" name="lastName" disabled="true" />

        <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="password-checkbox" checked />
        <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Insert Password" disabled>
        <input id="confirmpassword" type="password" class="form-control" name="confirmpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" disabled>
        <button id="updateUserBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" data-loading-text="Creating User..." disabled>Update User</button>
</sf:form>
```

My first attemp with javascript is below and it works only for the password fields but it is not connected with the edit button

```
$("input[type=password]").keyup(
            function() {
                var ucase = new RegExp("[A-Z]+");
                var lcase = new RegExp("[a-z]+");
                var num = new RegExp("[0-9]+");

                if ($("#password").val().length >= 8) {
                    $("#8char").removeClass("glyphicon-remove");
                    $("#8char").addClass("glyphicon-ok");
                    $("#8char").css("color", "#00A41E");
                } else {
                    $("#8char").removeClass("glyphicon-ok");
                    $("#8char").addClass("glyphicon-remove");
                    $("#8char").css("color", "#FF0004");
                }

                if (ucase.test($("#password").val())) {
                    $("#ucase").removeClass("glyphicon-remove");
                    $("#ucase").addClass("glyphicon-ok");
                    $("#ucase").css("color", "#00A41E");
                } else {
                    $("#ucase").removeClass("glyphicon-ok");
                    $("#ucase").addClass("glyphicon-remove");
                    $("#ucase").css("color", "#FF0004");
                }

                if (lcase.test($("#password").val())) {
                    $("#lcase").removeClass("glyphicon-remove");
                    $("#lcase").addClass("glyphicon-ok");
                    $("#lcase").css("color", "#00A41E");
                } else {
                    $("#lcase").removeClass("glyphicon-ok");
                    $("#lcase").addClass("glyphicon-remove");
                    $("#lcase").css("color", "#FF0004");
                }

                if (num.test($("#password").val())) {
                    $("#num").removeClass("glyphicon-remove");
                    $("#num").addClass("glyphicon-ok");
                    $("#num").css("color", "#00A41E");
                } else {
                    $("#num").removeClass("glyphicon-ok");
                    $("#num").addClass("glyphicon-remove");
                    $("#num").css("color", "#FF0004");
                }

                if ($("#password").val() == $("#confirmpassword").val()
                        && ($("#confirmpassword").val() != 0)) {
                    $("#pwmatch").removeClass("glyphicon-remove");
                    $("#pwmatch").addClass("glyphicon-ok");
                    $("#pwmatch").css("color", "#00A41E");
                } else {
                    $("#pwmatch").removeClass("glyphicon-ok");
                    $("#pwmatch").addClass("glyphicon-remove");
                    $("#pwmatch").css("color", "#FF0004");
                }

                if ($("#password").val().length >= 8
                        && ucase.test($("#password").val())
                        && lcase.test($("#password").val())
                        && num.test($("#password").val())
                        && $("#password").val() == $("#confirmpassword").val()
                        && ($("#confirmpassword").val() != 0)) {
                    $("#updateUserBtn").removeClass("btn-danger");
                    $("#updateUserBtn").addClass("btn-success");
                    $("#updateUserBtn").prop('disabled', false);
                } else {
                    $("#updateUserBtn").removeClass("btn-success");
                    $("#updateUserBtn").addClass("btn-danger");
                    $("#updateUserBtn").prop('disabled', true);
                }
            });
```

Comment: A `keyup` handler attached to the `form` element will be called for any field within it having a keyup.

Comment: seems a solution.... can you provide a small piece of code that illustrate that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `keyup` handler attached to the `form` element will be called for any field within it having a `keyup` event. That is because most events bubble up through all their ancestors and can be listened for at any level.

Small example as requested :)

```
$("form").keyup(
        function() {
            // your existing code here
        });
```

If you want to target only specific inputs for the changes, you could use a delegated handler instead attached to the form (this one is using the specific form id):

```
$("#formsubmit").on('keyup', 'input[type=text],input[type=password]',
        function() {
            // your existing code here
        });
```

This applies the selector at event time so is quite efficient, and also means the `this` value will be the control that changed (if that is useful to you).

As a general jQuery guideline, only run selectors once and save the element. This is faster & shorter and usually more readable. Also you can chain most jQuery functions together.

e.g.

```
 var $password = $("#password");
 var $8char = $("#8char");

 if ($password.val().length >= 8) {
        $8char.removeClass("glyphicon-remove").addClass("glyphicon-ok").css("color", "#00A41E");
```